# MATLAB: how can I plot centroids of different colors in this loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, plot, indexing

This code correctly counts the number of object for each horizontal band I previously divided my image in, and plots them with the same marker for every object in the different bands.

barray is a vector in which I store the 'height' of each band.

```
n = zeros(1,bandlength);    % preallocate space for counting objects in 
                              each band, with bandlength = total number 
                              of bands in which the image is 
                              partitioned

 for j = 1:bandlength   
        if j == 1
        n(j) = sum(centroidsY<(barray(j)));  % case for when j=1 for 
                                               indexing reasons
        plot(centroidsX,centroidsY,'r+','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
    hold on;
        else
        n(j) = sum(centroidsY>sum(barray(1:j-1)) & centroidsY<sum(barray(1:j)));
        plot(centroidsX,centroidsY,'b+','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on;
        end
 end
 disp(n);
```

I'd like to better this code, in particular I want it to plot the marker with the same color for elements of the same band. Same color inside the same band but different color for for each of the bands.

I thought about simply put a 'k' index for loop before the 'j' index for loop like:

```
for k = 1:numberOfBlobs
 for j = 1:bandlength   
        if j == 1
        n(j) = sum(centroidsY(k)<(barray(j)));  % case for when j=1 for 
                                               indexing reasons
        plot(centroidsX(k),centroidsY(k),'r+','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
    hold on;
        else
        n(j) = sum(centroidsY(k)>sum(barray(1:j-1)) & centroidsY(k)<sum(barray(1:j)));
        plot(centroidsX(k),centroidsY(k),'b+','MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on;
        end
 end
end
disp(n);
```

But this fails to correctly count the number of elements in each band, since disp(n) returns:

```
0 0 1 0
```

or other combinations where there's one 1 and the rest is 0.

Once this is solved, I'd need to modify the plot part to get same colour centroids for elements belonging to same band, but different between bands. Bandlength might have a big value sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: to get a point you need to tell `plot` that you want a marker not a line, `plot(centroidsX(k),centroidsY(k),'x','color',rand(1,3))` . your code is way to detailed. write a minimal example

Comment: @bla I added that bit of code for the if-else, plus a for `k = 1:length(centroidsY)` before the j-for-loop but this returns me a zeros array (minus a 1 somewhere) for n(j). Also, the markers are different for each single centroid, but I want the same marker type for each band. Thanks